# How to hide mat-checkbox indeterminate state icon and use background color instead?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I would like to hide the indeterminate state icon (minus icon) and use background color instead.
At the moment, I can change the background color during the indeterminate state using the css code below. However, the minus icon is still visible. I know I can do `display: none;` but that will not let the background color show.

```
.mat-checkbox-indeterminate.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background {
background: blue; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following CSS to hide the minus icon:

```
::ng-deep .mat-checkbox-indeterminate .mat-checkbox-background .mat-checkbox-mixedmark {
  display: none;
}
```

This means you'll get a solid background colour on the checkbox when it's in the indeterminate state, and this will change to a tick when all child checkboxes are checked:

[image]

Please see [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9dofuq-3atfng?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcheckbox-overview-example.css) for a demo.

Comment: `.mat-checkbox-indeterminate.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background {`
  `background: blue;`
   `}`

   `.mat-checkbox .mat-checkbox-mixedmark {`
       `display: none;`
    `}` Thanks, this is what I needed